# Self-written Mutex for 2+ Threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix, mutex

I have written the following code, and so far in all my tests it seems as if I have written a working Mutex for my 4 Threads, but I would like to get someone else's opinion on the validity of my solution.

```
typedef struct Mutex{
    int turn;
    int * waiting;
    int num_processes;
} Mutex;

void enterLock(Mutex * lock, int id){   
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < lock->num_processes; i++){
        lock->waiting[id] = 1;
        if (i != id && lock->waiting[i])
            i = -1;
        lock->waiting[id] = 0;
    }
    printf("ID %d Entered\n",id);
}

void leaveLock(Mutex * lock, int id){
    printf("ID %d Left\n",id);
    lock->waiting[id] = 0;
}

void foo(Muted * lock, int id){
    enterLock(lock,id);
    // do stuff now that i have access
    leaveLock(lock,id);
}
```

Comment: this code isn't complete though (or horribly wrong) .. Mutex.waiting is never pointing somewhere defined. apart from that, trying to write your own atomic primitives on non-atomic stuff C provides is definitely a bad idea and it's just a lot of work (but always doable) to prove where it can go wrong.  [the key is just to find the most problematic point for a random thread switch]

Comment: adding to my comment ... for reliable code, please just use `pthread_mutex_t` ... implementations might differ, but you will never find an implementation based on "pure" C because it always needs some atomic primitives.

Comment: as far as I can see, nothing prevents thread B from entering the same mutex after thread A already entered it and before thread A left it. The state of the Mutex is the same whether it is locked or unlocked.

Comment: just a side note..i like when someone tries to implement such a thing :-) try   implemeting a semaphore next time! +1

Comment: and then try implementing a counting semaphore on top of a binary semaphore ... there's an infamous paper about that, which was revised and again proven wrong :) best example for CS students why not to attempt such a thing :)

Comment: @Felix Palmen Hhh you'll never know what you'll get, mate!

Comment: As best as I can tell, *nothing* in the `for`-loop qualifies as a visible side-effect, so the compiler is free to arbitrarily reorder accesses. How can you have heard of `mutex`, but be completely ignorant of atomicity?

Comment: @EOF, as there is definitely missing code, I assumed at least some `volatile` qualifier. But of course, it's still wrong.

Comment: how? By writing thousands of lines of code without ever taking a class or reading a textbook.

Comment: ok @AndrewGrant -- then just read about atomic operations. what you need is, for example, an assembler instruction that tests the value of a memory location and at the same time modifies it if possible (non-interruptable). C doesn't give you that.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: C11 *does* give you atomics.

Comment: @EOF, feel free to give an example of usage, it might fit very well here ;) I didn't deal with C11 so far.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: C11 draft standard, `7.17 Atomics <stdatomic.h>, 7.17.7 Operations on atomic types, 7.17.7.4 The atomic_compare_exchange generic functions: _Bool atomic_compare_exchange_strong_explicit(volatile A *object, C *expected, C desired, memory_order success, memory_order failure);` As far as I understand, this is sufficient to implement *any* kind of atomic operation.

Comment: @EOF, I can imagine how it is used ... for an answer here, a concrete code example would be nice :) Still I guess you're right.

Comment: @RohitGupta This code is too example-ish for being a good Code Review question. I suggest reading [A Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users). This would get closed on Code Review as either "example code".

Answer (score 2):

I feel compelled writing an answer here because the question is a good one, taking into concern it could help others to understand the general problem with mutual exclusion. In your case, you came a long way to hide this problem, but you can't avoid it. It boils down to this:

```
01  /* pseudo-code */
02  if (! mutex.isLocked())
03        mutex.lock();
```

You always have to expect a thread switch between lines `02` and `03`. So there is a possible situation where two threads find `mutex` unlocked and be interrupted after that ... only to resume later and lock this mutex individually. You will have two threads entering the critical section at the same time.

What you definitely need to implement reliable mutual exclusion is therefore an atomic operation that tests a condition and at the same time sets a value without any chance to be interrupted meanwhile.

```
01  /* pseudo-code */
02  while (! test_and_lock(mutex));
```

As soon as this `test_and_lock` function cannot be interrupted, your implementation is safe. Until [c11](/questions/tagged/c11), C didn't provide anything like this, so implementations of `pthreads` needed to use e.g. assembly or special compiler intrinsics. With [c11](/questions/tagged/c11), there is finally a "standard" way to write atomic operations like this, but I can't give an example here, because I don't have experience doing that. For general use, the `pthreads` library will give you what you need.

**edit:** of course, this is still simplified -- in a multi-processor scenario, you need to ensure that even memory accesses are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

**The Problem I see in you code:**

The idea behind a `mutex` is to provide mutual exclusion, means that when `thread_a` is in the critical section, `thread_b` must wait(in case he wants also to enter) for `thread_a`.

This waiting part should be implemented in `enterLock` function. But what you have is a `for` loop which might end way before `thread_a` is done from the critical section and thus `thread_b` could also enter, hence you can't have mutual exclusion.

**Way to fix it:**

Take a look for example at [Peterson's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm) or Dekker's([more complicated](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12621/contrasting-peterson-s-and-dekker-s-algorithms)), what they did there is what's called `busy waiting` which is basically a `while` loop which says:
`while(i can't enter) { do nothing and wait...}`

Comment: I'm confused as to why you think my for loop may end before thread_a is done? Ill edit my post to show more information

Comment: in `for(i = 0; i < lock->num_processes; i++)` , `i` runs `num_processes` times, and then the `for loop` ends there, however, meanwhile `thread_a` not neccessarly been done, it could perform a heavy mission or somtheng

Comment: It runs an infinite number of times, until one iteration shows that every lock->waiting[i] is false. You may have miss read the for loop

Comment: @AndrewGrant the test for that might overlap with the change ... which is the *basic* problem with all attempts to do mutual exclusion without atomic primitives

Answer (score 1):

You are totally ignoring the topic of memory models. Unless you are on a machine with a sequential consistent memory model (which none of today's PC CPUs are), your code is incorrect, as any store executed by one thread is not necessarily immediately visible to other CPUs. However, exactly this seems to be an assumption in your code.

Bottom line: Use the existing synchronization primitives provided by the OS or a runtime library such a POSIX or Win32 API and don't try to be smart and implement this yourself. Unless you have years of experince in parallel programming as well as in-depth knowledge of CPU architecture, chances are quite good that you end up with an incorrect implementation. And debugging parallel programms can be hell...

Comment: It doesn't matter what the machine's memory model is: The *compiler* may reorder the memory accesses.

Answer (score 0):

After `enterLock()` returns, the state of the Mutex object is the same as before the function was called. Hence it will not prevent a second thread to enter the same Mutex object even before the first one released it calling `leaveLock()`. There is no mutual exclusiveness.